# Thread difficulties in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

Im trying to play an song then a person is calling my application. But then the `mediaElement1.play();` is used i just get an `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`. I have tried to use threading. But then the problem just moves. 
Best regard Morten Starck

Comment: I undersatnd english is not your first langauge, BUT: Where is the question? STATING A PROBLEM IS NOT ASKING A QUESTION. Please reword.

Comment: This (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it..) doesn't mean you need threading, but that it already is. The answer provided by Paul brings the mediaelement (back) to your main UI thread, where the UI magic happens. Just so you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
        if (!mediaElement1.CheckAccess())
            mediaElement1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)delegate
                {
                    mediaElement1.play();
                });
```